# Captionbeside flushright

Tags: captions

I would like to use the captionbeside environment from KOMAscript to display the caption on the right besides some content. I want it aligned to the right of the document though, not immediately right of the content.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=formel,                         % Name der Umgebung
  types=formeln,                       % Erweiterung (\listofschemes)
  float,                               % soll gleiten
  tocentryentrynumberformat=\bfseries, % voreingestellte Gleitparameter
  name=Formel,                         % Name in Überschriften
  listname={Formelverzeichnis},        % Listenname
  % counterwithin=chapter
]{lom}
\setuptoc{lom}{totoc}

\begin{document}
\begin{formel}[H]
      \begin{captionbeside}{\textbf{Druckverlust}}[r]
        $\Delta p_{WZ}=\Delta p\cdot\dfrac{\dot{V}^2_S}{\dot{V}^2_G}$
      \end{captionbeside}
      $\dot{V}^2_S = $ Spitzendurchfluss $\left[ m^3/h\right]$\\
      $\dot{V}^2_G = $ maximaler Durchfluss im Wasserzähler $\left[ m^3/h\right]$\\
      $\Delta p = $ Druckverlust bei $V_{max} \left[bar\right]$\\
      \label{formel:ohm}
    \end{formel}
\end{document}
```

This only displays the caption "Druckverlust" right of the formula, not on the right side of the page.

What I want
[image: goal]

What I get
[image: current]

Answer (score 1):

Adding 2 lines to you code will produce

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the margins

\usepackage{etoolbox}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pretocmd{\captionbelow}{\onelinecaptionstrue}{}{}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\DeclareNewTOC[
type=formel,                         % Name der Umgebung
types=formeln,                       % Erweiterung (\listofschemes)
float,                               % soll gleiten
tocentryentrynumberformat=\bfseries, % voreingestellte Gleitparameter
name=Formel,                         % Name in Überschriften
listname={Formelverzeichnis},        % Listenname
% counterwithin=chapter
]{lom}
\setuptoc{lom}{totoc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{formel}[H]
        \begin{captionbeside}{\textbf{Druckverlust}}[r]
            $\Delta p_{WZ}=\Delta p\cdot\dfrac{\dot{V}^2_S}{\dot{V}^2_G}$
        \end{captionbeside}
        $\dot{V}^2_S = $ Spitzendurchfluss $\left[ m^3/h\right]$\\
        $\dot{V}^2_G = $ maximaler Durchfluss im Wasserzähler $\left[ m^3/h\right]$\\
        $\Delta p = $ Druckverlust bei $V_{max} \left[bar\right]$\\
        \label{formel:ohm}
    \end{formel}
\end{document}
```